# Bash assigning a variable to a command output which will be a list of multiple word strings

Tags: arrays, string, bash, variable-assignment

This is the script which I am trying to run

```
bRules=(`aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket x |  jq '.Rules[]'.ID`)
echo "*** Total number of LifecycleRules ****  ${#bRules[@]}"
for rule in "${bRules[@]}"
do
    echo "Bucket: x, Rule: $rule"
done
```

Actual output

```
*** Total number of LifecycleRules ****  6
 Bucket: x, Rule: This
 Bucket: x, Rule: is
 Bucket: x, Rule: Rule-1
 Bucket: x, Rule: This
 Bucket: x, Rule: is
 Bucket: x, Rule: Rule-2
```

Expected output:

```
*** Total number of LifecycleRules ****  2
Bucket: x, Rule: This is Rule-1
Bucket: x, Rule: This is Rule-2
```

What needs to be change in my code snippet to get the desired output?  I'm kinda of lost to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on command substitution and word splitting. Use `readarray` (or `mapfile` if you prefer) and process substitution instead.

Your loop can also be simplified to a single `printf`.

```
readarray -t bRules < <(aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket x | jq '.Rules[]'.ID)
echo "*** Total number of LifecycleRules ****  ${#bRules[@]}"
printf 'Bucket: x, Rule: %s\n' "${bRules[@]}"
```

Read the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).